# Cannot locate the Microsoft Visual FoxPro support library

Tags: python, python-requests, visual-foxpro

I have recently updated the Requests package for Python (I also installed WireShark around the same time, but I'm not sure if that's relevant). Since doing this, whenever I try and execute a Python file from the command line that imports the Requests library, I receive a pop up on screen stating:

> "Cannot locate the Microsoft Visual FoxPro support library".

If I click <kbd>OK</kbd> on the prompt, the file executes as normal. I suspect that this is causing problems for my scheduled tasks that import Requests, as they have stopped running to completion since this issue has come about.

I used to have a FoxPro database installed on the machine; that's the only time I've ever even heard of Visual FoxPro. Apart from that, I have no idea why this has started showing up. If anybody knows why this might be happening and/or how I can get it to stop, it would be great to hear some suggestions. I'm happy to provide more details if necessary. Thank you.

EDIT: I've been able to stop the pop up message from appearing and get my scheduled tasks working by rolling back Requests to an older version. It would still be ideal if anyone could suggest what might be going on with the latest version that would cause the behavior that I described.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Requests package for python, but as a generic suggestion you could try http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to see what DLLs are trying to load.

Comment: Since the OLD code runs 'clean' and the NEW code throws the message, I'd begin by determining what the difference was between the 2 sets of code.  You might find that the NEW code calls a DLL or EXE which was created using Visual Foxpro.  Find that out first and we might be better able to assist you.

Answer (score 5):

The message above is caused by a Foxpro application not being able to locate its correct runtime libraries.

The below link will provide an installer for all of the Visual Foxpro runtime libraries. Just download the correct runtime installer and install the files to your PC to correct the problem.

http://www.foxpert.com/download/runtime.html